# Do Eigenvalues of an operator always converge to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying functional analysis and we proved in class that the eigenvalues $\mu_1\geq \mu_2\geq \cdots$ of a compact and self-adjoint operator defined on some Hilbert space converge to zero, i.e., $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu_n=0$. Does this hold true for other types of operators (non-compact, non-self adjoint) as well? I'm actually solving the Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem and noticed that the eigenvalues actually never converge to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The identity operator has only one eigen value, namely $1$.